# Sharepoint Online List Classic UI - Format Column/Row to be Red on certain Condition

Tags: sharepoint-list, jslink

I do not know JSLink, so I am struggling to figure this out. I have a drop down menu column and if the user selects one of the drop down menus (Lets say its called "Peer Review - Rushed") I would like the cell to show red, or even the whole row if need be. How do I do that?

I have this which works on the modern ui:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "span",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField == 'Peer Review - Rushed', 'Red', if(@currentField == 'Peer Review - Slow', 'Blue', 'Black'))"
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's how to color code the entire row: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/color-code-item-row-based-on-column-value-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013

Comment: @MikeSmith-MCT-MVP Thank you, you are amazing.